# Flutter Device Preview and Firebase Auth Incompatible

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

**Pubspec.yaml**
`dependencies:`
`flutter: sdk: flutter bloc: ^6.1.0 cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3 cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0 device_preview: ^0.5.5 firebase_auth: ^0.18.3 firebase_core: ^0.5.2 firebase_storage: ^5.0.1 fl_chart: ^0.12.2 flutter_bloc: ^6.1.1 flutter_sms: ^2.1.1 flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1 flutter_svg: ^0.19.1 google_nav_bar: ^3.1.0 http: ^0.12.2 liquid_swipe: ^1.5.0 location: ^3.2.1 page_transition: ^1.1.7+3 persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^3.1.0 regexpattern: ^1.0.0`

**ERROR RECEIVED**

**Because firebase_auth >=0.18.3 <=0.18.3 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2 and no versions of firebase_auth match >0.18.3+1 <0.18.4, firebase_auth >=0.18.3 <0.18.3+1 or >0.18.3+1 <0.18.4-∞ requires firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2.

Because firebase_auth >=0.18.4 <=0.18.4 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2+2 and firebase_auth >=0.18.4+1 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2+3, firebase_auth >=0.18.4 requires firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2+2.
Thus, firebase_auth >=0.18.3 <0.18.3+1 or >0.18.3+1 requires firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2.

And because firebase_auth 0.18.3+1 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2+1, firebase_auth >=0.18.3 requires firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2.

And because firebase_auth_web >=0.3.0-dev.1 depends on intl ^0.16.1 and every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2, firebase_auth >=0.18.3 is incompatible with flutter_localizations from sdk.

And because device_preview 0.5.5 depends on flutter_localizations any from sdk and no versions of device_preview match >0.5.5 <0.6.0, firebase_auth >=0.18.3 is incompatible with device_preview ^0.5.5.**

There are some dependency version issues, let me know how to correct it.

Comment: remove the version and use the key word `any` let me know if it solves. For instance, `firebase_auth: any`

Comment: I see the same firebase mess. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Using any solved my problem. Thank you @Hamza

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue, you can take the following steps to check for the compatible version

1. Change the version number of the `flutter_bloc` to `any`
2. This will resolve the issue
3. You can then check which version was automatically selected and use it